# instead of insert Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am having a problem with the Trigger below. I believe that the issue is when multiple rows are added to the database at once.

It needs to work for n* rows being inserted.

What the code is meant to be doing is upon an insert check the ESHID column vs another table the ID starts after 4 characters

so if there is a match and isPersonalised is 0 then I need to set status as 3 otherwise it should remain as whatever the original FulfilmentStatus was.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[setStatus] 
   ON  [dbo].[ESH_OrderLine]
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ESH_OrderLine(

        OrderID,
        ESHID,
        ESHVersion,
        GBPPrice,
        Currency,
        FulfilmentStatus,
        FulfilmentDate
    )SELECT

        OrderID,
        ESHID,
        ESHVersion,
        GBPPrice,
        Currency,
        (
            SELECT "Status" =
            CASE
                WHEN isPersonalised = 1 THEN '0'    --PERSONALISED CD
                ELSE '3'                            -- NON PERSONALISED CD
            END
            FROM KSAT_CDs
            WHERE ID= SUBSTRING( (  
                                    SELECT ESHID FROM INSERTED
                                    WHERE ESHID like 'PHZB%' 
                                ),5,10)

            UNION
            SELECT "Status" =
                CASE
                WHEN ESHID = 'PNP' THEN '0'     --POSTAGE AND PACKING
            ELSE '4'                            --DOWNLOAD
            END
            FROM INSERTED
            WHERE ESHID NOT LIKE 'PHZB%'
        ) as FulfilmentStatus,
        FulfilmentDate
     FROM
    INSERTED

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Does changing the first part of your `union` to this help?

```
SELECT "Status" =
            CASE
                WHEN k.isPersonalised = 1 THEN '0'    --PERSONALISED CD
                ELSE '3'                            -- NON PERSONALISED CD
            END
            FROM KSAT_CDs k
            inner join inserted i on k.ID = substring(i.ESHID, 5, 10)
            where i.ESHID like 'PHZB%'
```